# Do I need Intel vPro in my new laptop?

Tags: vpro

I'm looking for a new laptop to replace a 2017 Dell XPS 13. I'm a software developer.

I've seen a very appealing HP Dragonfly machine that ticks all my boxes - I was about to push the button and order it when I noticed that that particular machine has the i7 1165-G7 cpu which isn't marked vPro - there is a machine above it which has the 1185 cpu which is labelled vPro (and which sells for a bit more money).

My question is: do I need a  vPro cpu in my life or is it something which only really benefits IT administrators (for remote management etc.) ? I will eventually need to be able to run Docker and possibly other virtualisation software on the machine so I don't want to put it out of the running by buying an incompatible machine.

Comment: What vPro feature do you require exactly? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: At a guess I'd probably assume that vPro includes all of the corporate management extensions as well as things like Trusted Execution and SGX. The 1165 claims to support VTx and VT-d so will absolutely do virtualisation well enough. I cannot say for you but for me personally as a home user I think I wouldn't really care unless the 1185 was faster or had better graphics, but neither of those appear to be the case as the 1185 seems to purely be a release for businesses that have additional security requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You do not a vPro CPU to run 64-bit Virtual Machines fast and smoothly.

VMware, Hyper-V, Virtual Box, WSL, and docker type software all run on my non-vPro machine.

It is of course up to you if you wish, but from my point of view and a lot of experience, no issue if you do not have a vPro CPU

I can and work a whole day within a fast Virtual Machine and have anything I need on my Windows 11 Host without vPro.

Comment: “You do not a vPro CPU to run 64-bit Virtual Machines fast and smoothly.” - What? Couple words seem to be missing fro this sentence

Comment: You are correct and I edited my post to correct. Apologies for the typo.

Answer (score 1):

To understand whether you can benefit from vPro, it’s important to understand what it is. vPro is mostly *marketing*. I unfortunately cannot provide an authoritative list of logo requirements. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_vPro) and the top of my head, there are, among others:

- Certain Intel CPUs (with hardware-assisted virtualization etc.)
- Certain Intel Wi-Fi hardware
- Certain Intel Ethernet interfaces
- Intel Active Management Technology (AMT)
- Signed firmware updates
- Some other low-level security/anti-theft stuff

The first three points are also of interest to consumers/“pro-sumers”. High-performance network connectivity is great. So are CPUs with lots of features.

However, if you take a good look, you can see that you’ll get most of these benefits even without a vPro logo. Just check the specs of the device you want to buy and whether they satisfy your requirements. Especially hardware-assisted virtualization is present in many, if not most, modern CPUs.

AMT is a special case and of interest to enthusiasts, because it offers out-of-band (of sorts) [remote KVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch#Remote_KVM_devices). This is usually the domain of expensive add-on devices and/or server-grade hardware. However, you probably don’t need that. Provisioning AMT was difficult last I tried.